# TSQL Pivot with group by

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I’m using the PIVOT clause to convert this data:

```
ComponenteID Descripcion                              PosicionID  Email                                                        Nivel
------------ ---------------------------------------- ----------- ------------------------------------------------------------ -----
9            Maquinaria                               19          monica.rodriguez@definity.com                           1
9            Maquinaria                               19          monica.rodriguez@definity.com                           2
9            Maquinaria                               19          monica.rodriguez@definity.com                           3
9            Maquinaria                               150         fulano.detal@definityfirst.com                               1
```

To:

```
TipoComponenteId Descripcion                              AprobadoresNivel1                                                                   AprobadoresNivel2                                                                   AprobadoresNivel3
---------------- ---------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
9                Maquinaria                               19 - monica.rodriguez@definity.com, 150 - fulano.detal@definity.com                                             19 - monica.rodriguez@definity.com                                             19 - monica.rodriguez@definity.com
```

But because the MAX clause off course is just showing one element in AprobadoresNivel1 (third column) (see below)

```
TipoComponenteId Descripcion                              AprobadoresNivel1                                                                   AprobadoresNivel2                                                                   AprobadoresNivel3
---------------- ---------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
9                Maquinaria                               19 - monica.rodriguez@definityfirst.com                                             19 - monica.rodriguez@definityfirst.com                                             19 - monica.rodriguez@definityfirst.com
```

Is there a way to use a group by in the PIVOT clause? is there other way to accomplish this?

Comment: PIVOT groups rows implicitly, otherwise it wouldn't be able to use `MAX` or any other aggregate function. Post your query

Comment: BTW the only way to create a value like `19 - monica.rodriguez@definity.com, 150 - fulano.detal@definity.com ` is to use `STRING_AGG`, which is available in SQL Server 2017. Perhaps your real question is how to aggregate strins in earlier versions?

Comment: I'm using sql server 2017 and my objective is to show the data as the third table in my question. My first approach was pivot tables, but if anyone knows a better way that can point me I’ll gladly try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well with the help of Panagiotis Kanavos i manage to do this, that solve my problem:

```
SELECT 
     tc.ID TipoComponenteId  ,tc.Descripcion,
    STRING_AGG(
        CASE 
            WHEN ac.Nivel = 1 THEN (CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),ac.PosicionID) + ' - ' + e.Email)
            ELSE null
        END,',') AS AprobadoresNivel1,
    STRING_AGG(
        CASE 
            WHEN ac.Nivel = 2 THEN  (CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),ac.PosicionID) + ' - ' + e.Email)
            ELSE null
        END,',') AS AprobadoresNivel2,
    STRING_AGG(
        CASE 
            WHEN ac.Nivel = 3 THEN  (CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),ac.PosicionID) + ' - ' + e.Email)
            ELSE null
        END,',') AS AprobadoresNivel3
FROM AprobadoresComision ac
    INNER JOIN TipoComponente tc ON tc.ID = ac.ComponenteID
    INNER JOIN Posicion p ON p.PosicionID = ac.PosicionID
    INNER JOIN Empleado e ON e.EmpleadoID = p.EmpleadoID
WHERE ac.Estatus = 1 
    AND ac.ComponenteID = 9 
GROUP BY tc.ID,tc.Descripcion
```

Thanks